# How to access the buttonStyle object inside of one button using JavaScript in QML 5.2

Tags: qt, qml

Below is my Qml code:

```
Button {
    id: newMenu

    anchors {
        top: topMenu.top
        topMargin: 15
        left: topMenu.left
        leftMargin: 16
    }

    text: "New"
    iconSource: "../images/New.png"

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true         //this line will enable mouseArea.containsMouse
        onClicked: {
            newProjectFileDlg.visible = true
        }
        onEntered: {
            console.log(tt1);
        }
    }

    style: ButtonStyle {
        id: buttonStyle
        background: Rectangle {
            id: tt1
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 25
            border.width: 0
            radius: 4
            color: mousearea.entered ? "lightsteelblue" : "#2e2e2e"
        }
    }
```

I want to access this button's style property, change the background.color when mouse is hover. But the console.log outpu is always

```
qrc:/qmls/menu.qml:40: ReferenceError: tt1 is not defined
```

How to get the element using JavaScript? Or do we have other approach to change background color when mouse is entered.

Comment: Why did you use tt1 as opposed to buttonStyle? Does that raise a similar ReferenceError?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, it outputs qrc:/qmls/menu.qml:40: ReferenceError: buttonStyle is not defined

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if is what you was looking for, but you can change background color of a ButtonStyle simply using "control", like that way:

color: control.pressed ? "#f00" : (control.hovered||control.activeFocus ? "#0f0" : "#00f")

Answer (score 4):

Answering to your question, you should define public property like:

```
Button {
    id: root

    property color backgroundColor: pressed ? 'skyblue' 
                                            : mousearea.entered ? "lightsteelblue" 
                                                                : "#2e2e2e"
    ...

    MouseArea { id: mousearea; ... }

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectanlge { color: root.backgroundColor; ... }
    }
}
```

and then use is property to override default implementation.

But,

You are trying to use styles in a completely wrong way. `Style` is a visual representation of `Control`'s state and should't be changed manually in run-time. So, a proper way is to bind control properties to style (e.g. using property [`control`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html#control-prop)).

```
style: ButtonStyle {
    background: Rectangle {
         color: control.hovered ? 'lightsteelblue' 
                                : 'skyblue'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar without using styles by nesting a rectangle inside the button and then using the onHoveredChanged property to modify the opacity. An example is below. I did it this way to avoid conflicting with the normal button style's hover effect.

```
Button { 
   text: "Push me"
   Rectangle{ 
      id: myRectId 
      anchors.fill: parent 
      anchors.margins: 1 
      color: "green" 
      opacity : .2 
    }
    onHoveredChanged: hovered ? myRectId.opacity = 0 : myRectId.opacity = .2; 
 }
```

This ends up looking like this:
[image: Example of QML button with different background color]